# Assigning value to the address of member of a struct pointer

Tags: c

I have this code

```
  struct abc *obj=(struct abc *)malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
  uint8_t **j=(uint8_t *)(&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));
  *j=5;
  printf("%d\n",obj->j);
```

What I am trying to do is to just move into the area pointed to by `struct abc *obj` and change the value of `obj->j`. I have created pointer to pointer that contains the address of `&obj+sizeof(uint8_t)` in this `sizeof(uint8_t)` will get us passed the area possessed by `obj->i` which is also uint8_t. but the code is not really working when I print `obj->j` which is still `0` How can I move into the memory area and change the value of j so `obj->j` will print 5

My system processor is x86-64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please add the definition of `struct abc`. I presume it looks like:

```
struct abc {
    uint8_t byte_we_want_to_skip;
    uint8_t j;
};
```

In this line:

```
uint8_t **j=(uint8_t *)(&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));
```

This says take the address of `obj` as a `struct abc` pointer, then add `sizeof(uint8_t)` ie 1 to it, but since the type of the expression is `struct abc *`, it is one `sizeof(struct abc)` bytes that you move, which is probably not what you want. Also, that should be `uint8_t *j`. So, what you should be using:

```
uint8_t *j = (uint8_t *)((char *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Note also that all this pointer fiddling is undefined behaviour, so it is not guaranteed to work everywhere. [`offsetof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) is a better alternative, used like so:

```
uint8_t *j = (char *) &obj + offsetof(obj, j);
```

Comment: Indeed the structure members (i and j) are not necessarily in the original order, excellent point.

Comment: It might be "implementation-defined", or it might actually be OK, as I think for bytes there is no padding by definition?

Comment: I would not risk it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307550/are-bits-in-the-structure-guaranteed : this link missed my further experiments where it was not giving the expected result by using pointer arithmetic to access struct members

Comment: `This says take the address of obj as a struct abc pointer, then add sizeof(uint8_t) ie 1 to it, but since the type of the expression is struct abc *, it is one sizeof(struct abc) bytes that you move` can I change `uint8_t *j = (uint8_t *)((char *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));` to `uint8_t *j = (uint8_t *)((uint8_t *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));`?

Comment: The cast does not matter, its more about the way you access your items, here you assume that you will access the value of j by skipping i, but in some systems, with some compilers, and with some optimization flags, it will not be true. NB: At home its perfectly fine to try, and with two bytes it should work as intended.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL how do I change the value of `*j` is it like `j=5;` its still printing 0

Comment: @KenY-N can u please tell the header file of `offsetof()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to change the value of j by accessing the memory location.
You can do so by directly accessing the location like this.

```
uint_t *j = &(obj->j);
*j = 5;
```

But if you want to change the value using skipping bytes then Ken Y-N's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the address of obj without & because *obj is already a pointer:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc {
    uint8_t byte_we_want_to_skip;
    uint8_t j;
};

int main(void) {
    struct abc *obj= malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    uint8_t *j =  (uint8_t*)((char *)obj+ sizeof(uint8_t)); // remove the &
    *j = 5;
    printf("address of obj => %p - value in obj->j: %d\n",obj, obj->j);
    printf("address of   j => %p - value at j address: %d \n", j, *j);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
address of obj => 0x55bbc5f84260 - value in obj->j: 5
address of   j => 0x55bbc5f84261 - value at j address: 5
```

---

Or you can have your struct on the stack and then you can use & to access its address:

```c
int main(void) {
    struct abc obj;
    uint8_t *j =  (uint8_t*)((char *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));
    *j = 5;

    printf("address of obj => %p - value in obj.j: %d\n", &obj, obj.j);
    printf("address of   j => %p - value at j address: %d \n", j, *j);

    uint16_t *a =  (uint16_t*)((char *)j - 1);
    printf("address of   a => %p - value at a address: %x \n", a, *a); // will print j * 100 in hexa
    *a = 42 | 3 << 8;
    printf("\naddress of obj => %p - value in obj.i: %d\n", &obj, obj.i);
    printf("address of obj => %p - value in obj.j: %d\n", &(obj.j), obj.j);
    printf("address of   j => %p - value of j: %d \n", j, *j);
    return 0;
}
```

I added an uint16_t to illustrate a bit more, output:

```
address of obj => 0x7ffecc5fa536 - value in obj.j: 5
address of   j => 0x7ffecc5fa537 - value at j address: 5 
address of   a => 0x7ffecc5fa536 - value at a address: 500 

address of obj => 0x7ffecc5fa536 - value in obj.i: 42
address of obj => 0x7ffecc5fa537 - value in obj.j: 3
address of   j => 0x7ffecc5fa537 - value of j: 3
```

*NB: We get 0x0500 because of [little endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness): inside the cpu bytes are 0x00 followed by 0x05, but the variable `a` will read bytes values from right to left*

Comment: `(uint8_t*)((char *)obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));` (char*) is 8 bytes how it promoted the address by 8 bits for `uint8_t` for the space of  `uint8_t byte_we_want_to_skip;` from definition of struct abc. Doesn't it promotes 8 bytes instead of 8 bits?

Comment: uint8_t is 8 bits, but the pointer is 8 bytes, char * is widely used for pointer arithmetic. Here you tell to point to the address of abc and to skip 1 byte (8bits) in order to access the second member of your struct abc.

Comment: so you means even though `char *` is 8 bytes but doing (char *) points to char sized address which is 1 byte. So why not doing `uint8_t **j =  (uint8_t**)((uint8_t *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));` instead of `uint8_t **j =  (uint8_t**)((char *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));`?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic with char * pointers uses byte offsets, because sizeof(char) is 1 by definition. Note that you could perfectly use uint8_t *, it will work, but for historical reasons, at the beginning only pointer arithmetic using char * was possible, so it became a habit that when you deal with pointer arithmetic you keep using char * to have your bytes offset.

Comment: What's the point of `uint8_t **j =  (uint8_t**)((char *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));` ? You can have `uint8_t *j =  (uint8_t*)((char *)&obj+ sizeof(uint8_t));     *j = 5;`

Comment: there is no point, I was just trying to follow op's logic ;)

Comment: @awakened seg fault at printf("%d\n",obj->j);

Comment: I added another printf that shows you the address of both obj and j, so that you see with your own eyes the difference

Comment: @Alex, there wouldn't be any segmentation fault.You're assigning an address to the pointer.